# mongodb $OR statement

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a small issue with the following MongoDB PHP script

```
$collection = $this->db->retail_details;
        $array = array('$OR'=>array(
            "salesperson"=>new MongoId($uid),
            "Manager"=>new MongoId($uid)
        ));
        $cursor = $collection->find($array);
```

I have all the rows saleperson and Manager and I am senging thw correct $UID for the manager it wont match the salesperson but it should still return the data as it matches the Manager MongoID.

Comment: Erm .. what exactly is the issue?

Comment: it doesn't work ... ? i really wonder, if people are trying the stuff others bring up. and again i do not understand, why this question got closed. @casperOne ... what about adding a question mark next time instead of closing the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators in mongodb are case-sensitive. So you should use "$or" rather than "$OR". But i think that your query is incorrect, too, because "$or" requires an indexed array for it's criteria:

```
$collection = $this->db->retail_details;
$array = array('$or'=>array(
    array("salesperson"=>new MongoId($uid)),
    array("Manager"=>new MongoId($uid))
));
$cursor = $collection->find($array);
```

This should work, in my opinion.